# Big Query: create table from first key in JSON only

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table from JSON files in BigQuery and want just one column which will represent the first key `'id'` only.

Creating a schema with only one column causes errors because all of the JSON keys in the input files are considered.

Is there a way to create a table that corresponds to only specific JSON keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t create a table from a `JSON` file in `BigQuery` with just one column from the `JSON` file. You can create a feature request in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list.).

You have these options:

**Option 1**

- Don't import as `JSON`, but as CSV instead (define null character as
  separator)
- Each line has only one column - the full `JSON` string
- Parse inside `BigQuery` with maximum flexibility (JSON parsing
  functions and even JS)

**Option 2**

Do a 2-step import:

- Import as a new table with all the columns.
- Append "`SELECT column1 FROM [newtable]`" into the existing table.